# Ember.js: how to get input element ID for use in label

Tags: ember.js, ember.js-view

I have a scenario where I can't wrap the label around an input element, so it has to look something like this:

```
<label>Name</label>
{{input value=name}}
```

I'd like to set the label's for attribute to match the input element's ID so that the rendered output is something like this:

```
<label for="ember351">Name</label>
<input type="text" value="" id="ember351" />
```

How can I get a reference to the element ID? I've seen some solutions where you use an Ember.TextField view, but I'm looking for a solution that supports the input helper (i.e. {{input}})

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can scope a custom ID for the input element to the current view by using the [component / view ID](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Component.html#property_elementId) as a prefix. This will help you avoid naming collisions outside the view. You'll need a [concat helper](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/v1.13.13/packages/ember-htmlbars/lib/helpers/-concat.js) (included as of Ember v1.13.x). Or you can always create one, of course.

```
<label for="{{concat elementId '-name'}}">Name</label>
{{input value=name id=(concat elementId '-name')}}
```

Should render something like:

```
<label for="ember351-name">Name</label>
<input type="text" value="" id="ember351-name />
```

Comment: still valid in 12.2017 on ember 2.13

Answer (score 4):

You can still set the id with input helpers. So

```
<label for="name">Name</label>
{{input value=name id="name"}}
```

will result in

```
<label for="name">Name</label>
<input type="text" value="" id="name">
```

Comment: I'd like to avoid hard coded IDs, because it can result in name collision.

Comment: You can also supply a variable just as easily to each. as in `<label {{bind-attr for=nameId}}>Name</label>
{{input value=name id=nameId}}`

Comment: or you wrap the input inside the label.

Answer (score 4):

To flesh out these answers there is a more flexible way by use of an HTMLBars helper:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="{{guid-for this "name"}}">Your name:</label>
  {{input id=(guid-for this "name")
          type="text"
          value=value
          placeholder="Enter your name…"}}
</div>
```

The `app/helpers/guid-for.js` HTMLBars helper could look like this:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Helper.helper(function([obj, suffix]) {
  Ember.assert('Must pass a valid object', obj);
  return [Ember.guidFor(obj), suffix].join('-');
});
```